# How to use the values from a dictionary appropriately in a function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm working on a piece of code and I can't seem to figure out how to use the items from the dictionary in the function. I want the output to give several lines, in this manner:

```
Christy is normal weight
Edward is obese
Helena is overweight
George is overweight
Sophia is normal weight
```

The function has to contain the parameters sex, waist and hip. I tried several things but it still doesn't work. So I'm trying to get this code to work and give the desired output.

```
christy = {"name": "Christy", "sex": "female", "waist": 73, "hip": 93}
edward = {"name": "Edward", "sex": "male", "waist": 110, "hip": 110}
helena = {"name": "Helena", "sex": "female", "waist": 77, "hip": 92}
george = {"name": "George", "sex": "male", "waist": 91, "hip": 101}
sophia = {"name": "Sophia", "sex": "female", "waist": 76, "hip": 96}

people = [christy, edward, helena, george, sophia]

def waist_to_hip_ratio_2(sex, waist, hip):
    if sex == "female":
        waist1 = waist
        hip1 = hip
        whr = waist1 / hip1
        if whr < 0.8:
            return "person is normal weight"
        elif 0.8 <= whr <= 0.84:  
            return "person is overweight"
        else:
            return "person is obese"
    if sex == "male":
        waist2 = waist
        hip2 = hip
        whr = waist2 / hip2
        if whr < 0.9:
            return "person is normal weight"
        elif 0.9 <= whr <= 0.99:     
            return "person is overweight"
        else:
            return "person is obese"
    for person in people:
        if person == christy:
            name = christy.get("name")
            sex = christy.get("sex")
            waist = christy.get("waist")
            hip = christy.get("hip")
            print(name and waist_to_hip_ratio_2(sex, waist, hip))
        if person == edward:
            sex = edward.get("sex")
            waist = edward.get("waist")
            hip = edward.get("hip")
            print(name and waist_to_hip_ratio_2(sex, waist, hip))
        if person == helena:
            sex = helena.get("sex")
            waist = helena.get("waist")
            hip = helena.get("hip")
            print(name and waist_to_hip_ratio_2(sex, waist, hip))
        if person == george:
            sex = george.get("sex")
            waist = george.get("waist")
            hip = george.get("hip")
            print(name and waist_to_hip_ratio_2(sex, waist, hip))
        if person == sophia:
            sex = sophia.get("sex")
            waist = sophia.get("waist")
            hip = sophia.get("hip")
            print(name and waist_to_hip_ratio_2(sex, waist, hip))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes I made to your code:

1. Changed "*person is* {weight type}" to just returning "{weight type}" so you can add the person's name after.
2. Removed the useless variables `weight1`, `hip1`, `weight2`, `hip2`.
3. Changed `if` to `elif` so python only checks once *(optional change)*
4. Took the `for` loop out of the function that calculates the weight type of every person.
5. Removed all the `if` statements from the for loop - instead of checking if the person is equal the one of the variables and then taking the values out of the variable, you could just take the values out of the `person` variable instead!
6. Fixed the `print` statement in the loop so it prints out in the format you requested.

Here's the new code:

```
christy = {"name": "Christy", "sex": "female", "waist": 73, "hip": 93}
edward = {"name": "Edward", "sex": "male", "waist": 110, "hip": 110}
helena = {"name": "Helena", "sex": "female", "waist": 77, "hip": 92}
george = {"name": "George", "sex": "male", "waist": 91, "hip": 101}
sophia = {"name": "Sophia", "sex": "female", "waist": 76, "hip": 96}

people = [christy, edward, helena, george, sophia]

def waist_to_hip_ratio_2(sex, waist, hip):
    if sex == "female":
        whr = waist / hip
        if whr < 0.8:
            return "normal weight"
        elif 0.8 <= whr <= 0.84:  
            return "overweight"
        else:
            return "obese"
    elif sex == "male":
        whr = waist / hip
        if whr < 0.9:
            return "normal weight"
        elif 0.9 <= whr <= 0.99:     
            return "overweight"
        else:
            return "obese"

for person in people:
    name = person.get("name")
    sex = person.get("sex")
    waist = person.get("waist")
    hip = person.get("hip")
    print(name, "is", waist_to_hip_ratio_2(sex, waist, hip))
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer, it really clarifies it. But I do have a question about point 5. I don't really understand how the program goes trough the dictionary and calculates the whr for each person in the list.

Comment: So, the `people` list is a list of dictionaries of people, right? So, when you loop through the `people` list, the current dictionary is stored in `person`. You don't need to check if the `person` variable is an actual dictionary and then take the value out of the dictionary (for example, you check if `person == christy` and then take values out of `christy`) because the `person` variable already contains the contents of `christy`, so you can take the values straight out of the `person` variable.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This code works. If you have any questions I am happy to answer them in the comments.

```
christy = {"name": "Christy", "sex": "female", "waist": 73, "hip": 93}
edward = {"name": "Edward", "sex": "male", "waist": 110, "hip": 110}
helena = {"name": "Helena", "sex": "female", "waist": 77, "hip": 92}
george = {"name": "George", "sex": "male", "waist": 91, "hip": 101}
sophia = {"name": "Sophia", "sex": "female", "waist": 76, "hip": 96}

people = [christy, edward, helena, george, sophia]

def waist_to_hip_ratio_2(sex, waist, hip):
    if sex == "female":
        waist1 = waist
        hip1 = hip
        whr = waist1 / hip1
        if whr < 0.8:
            return "person is normal weight"
        elif 0.8 <= whr <= 0.84:
            return "person is overweight"
        else:
            return "person is obese"
    if sex == "male":
        waist2 = waist
        hip2 = hip
        whr = waist2 / hip2
        if whr < 0.9:
            return "person is normal weight"
        elif 0.9 <= whr <= 0.99:
            return "person is overweight"
        else:
            return "person is obese"
for person in people:
    name = person["name"]
    sex = person["sex"]
    waist = person["waist"]
    hip = person["hip"]
    print(waist_to_hip_ratio_2(sex, waist, hip).replace("person" , name))
```

Output:

```
Christy is normal weight
Edward is obese
Helena is overweight
George is overweight
Sophia is normal weight
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I have a question about the code you added. How does python "know" to seek for "name" and "sex" etc in the dictionary when you say "for person in people", because then it goes through the list of people right?

Comment: It will consider person to be people[0] then people[1] etc. Because each person in people is the name of a dictionary python will understand that you are referencing the dictionary and allow you to index the keys from it. Because the keys are uniform you only need one loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can do:

```
christy = {"name": "Christy", "sex": "female", "waist": 73, "hip": 93}
edward = {"name": "Edward", "sex": "male", "waist": 110, "hip": 110}
helena = {"name": "Helena", "sex": "female", "waist": 77, "hip": 92}
george = {"name": "George", "sex": "male", "waist": 91, "hip": 101}
sophia = {"name": "Sophia", "sex": "female", "waist": 76, "hip": 96}

people = [christy, edward, helena, george, sophia]

for person in people:
    if person['sex'] == 'male': # Set the thresholds depending on gender for each iteration
        a, b = 0.9, 0.99
    else:
        a, b = 0.8, 0.84
        
    if person['waist']/person['hip'] < a:
        print(f"{person['name']} is normal weight")
    elif b >= person['waist']/person['hip'] >= a:
        print(f"{person['name']} is overweight")
    else:
        print(f"{person['name']} is obese")
```

Output:

```
Christy is normal weight
Edward is obese
Helena is overweight
George is overweight
Sophia is normal weight
```